How to create a flowchart in mermaid with inputs from observable? Possibly done within Quarto for R
I would like to show a calculation process using a flowchart. In each node of the flowchart the result or the input given by the user should be shown.
As I understand this should be possible using observable and mermaid as shown in this page using ${input} to recall the observable input.
I am struggling to replicate this in Quarto becasue, I believe, when using a {mermaid} code block, the ${input} is not recognised. See the code below.
viewof input1 = Inputs.number({ label: "Input 1", value: 0, min: 0, max: 100 })
viewof input2 = Inputs.number({ label: "Input 2", value: 0, min: 0, max: 100 })

// Perform a simple calculation (sum of two inputs)
sum = input1 + input2

// Display the result
html`<strong>Sum: ${sum}</strong>`

graph TD
A--> ${sum}
B--> ${sum}

In this last code block A and B should be replaced by input1 and input2 but this does not seem to work.
Do you have any suggestion?

You could use mermaid inside your observable (ojs) code with quotes like this:
---
title: "Test"
format: html
---

```{ojs}
viewof input1 = Inputs.number({ label: "Input 1", value: 0, min: 0, max: 100 })
viewof input2 = Inputs.number({ label: "Input 2", value: 0, min: 0, max: 100 })

// Perform a simple calculation (sum of two inputs)
sum = input1 + input2

// Display the result
html`<strong>Sum: ${sum}</strong>`

mermaid`graph TD
${input1}--> ${sum}
${input2}--> ${sum}
`
```

Output:


wonderful! thanks
